# Be the first transaction after another

Tags: gas, bsc

What's the most efficient way to win a "fastest finger" type of contest?  I need to monitor for a transaction by a 3rd party, after that transaction, I need to be the first to submit a transaction.  I know that increasing gas could get me mined first, but if someone gets into the block before me, or into the same block with the original transaction, I could still lose.  It's also worth mentioning that I'm competing on BSC, so the block times are 3 seconds.

Is there a way to make sure I'm in the block immediately following the transaction.

Some ideas, let me know if I'm off base.

1. Spam transactions within a timeframe.  Hope I'm first.
2. Spam calls to check status of contract.  If it meets a criteria, submit transaction.
3. Monitor mempool.  When I see the transaction that I'm watching for, send one of my own with high gas.  Wouldn't this risk getting my transaction in before the one I'm watching for?

Comment: Did you find the answer? Would really love to know to know the idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The spam uses a lot of bnb because of heaps of transactions needed. Don't even think to trade with spam bot if you don't snipe with a high amount.
I recommend using mempool transaction and need to use the same gas fee otherwise you will get frontrun and fail transaction.